# Multistep Equation with Square Root Confusion

Tags: square-numbers

Alright, so I have $4 * \sqrt{3} = \sqrt{x}$
So I squared the entire equation to get
$$16 * 3 = x$$
$$x = 48$$
Is this correct? Or do I only square the $\sqrt{3}$ part on the left side of the equation?

Comment: Looks beautiful.

Answer (score 2):

If you do something to one side of the equation you have to do it to the other. You are correct to square the entire left hand side.

$$a\sqrt{b} = \sqrt{x}$$
$$ (a\sqrt{b})^2 = (\sqrt{x})^2$$
$$ a^2b = x$$

Answer (score 1):

You can easily check, of course - what is the square root of $48$? But that is simply retracing your steps through your solution.

But essentially, you were correct - squaring both sides of the equation should give another valid equation, but squaring only one term will generally not.